# How to create a hard link to a directory or a file using QT on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, hardlink

How to create a hard link to a directory or a file using QT on Windows?

[QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html#link) can only create shortcut on Windows.

Comment: What's wrong with using native APIs?

Comment: You can't do this with Qt.

Comment: CreateHardLink can only create link to file not directory.

Comment: There is no such thing as a hard link to a directory.  Only files can be hardlinked.  For a directory, the only options are a symbolic link or a junction point.

Comment: I see, got confused by the command mklink /J and /H. Thanks @HarryJohnston